# jQuery get scroll position before scroll to temporarily disable scroll using scrollTop() position when at full screen

Tags: jquery

I have an animation that runs at full screen at the top of my site on site load. I want to **disable scroll** for the time the animation is running (15 seconds), but ONLY if the Y-scroll position is equal 0, to prevent the scroll being disabled if the site is loading with #anchors.

The problem is that `.scrollTop()` is not outputting the scroll position **before** the actual scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(height); // no output before scroll

    if(height  === 0) {
      //$("body").css({"overflow" : "hidden", "height" : "100%"});  //Lock scroll
    }
});


setTimeout(function () {
    $("body").css({"overflow" : "auto", "height" : "auto"}); 
}, 15000);
```

**How can I detect the scroll position BEFORE scroll is actually done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `$(window).scrollTop();` when the document is loaded. If the document was loaded at y 0 then add your event listener to scroll. Once 15 seconds have elapsed, allow scrolling and remove the event listener.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop(); // Get scroll height the page loaded at 

    // If we loaded at 0, add the scroll event listener.
    if (scrollHeight == 0) {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $("body").css({ "overflow": "hidden", "height": "100%" });  //Lock scroll

            setTimeout(function () {
                $("body").css({ "overflow": "auto", "height": "auto" });
                $(window).unbind("scroll");
            }, 15000);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I removed the: `$(window).scroll(function () { }` part to make the scroll lock work before first scroll!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is helpful:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).mousedown(function(event) {
     if(event.target === $('html')[0] && event.clientX >= document.documentElement.offsetWidth)
       var height = $(window).scrollTop();
       console.log(height); // output before scroll
   })
})
```